# JPA query.getResultList()

Tags: oracle, jpa, eclipselink

The following is the Oracle DB define:

```
classId char(8)    userId char(1)
 666666                  2
```

I'm creating a query to get a list from DB with EclipseLink 2.3.1. the following is the code.

```
Query query = em.createQuery("select classId from user where userId = ?")
query.setParameter(1,"2");
List<Object[]> list = query.getResultList();
```

But I get the classId is "666666" not "666666  ". It seems the query.getResultList() auto delete the whitespace? Why?

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13352818/avoid-char-trimming-when-using-eclipselink

Comment: Thank you very much. I have solved the problem.